# Pass cookies to SFSafariViewController from my native app

Tags: ios, webview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I need to have a seamless login from my native app to SFSafariViewController is that even possible

I do use webview in my app but there are certain parts which requires SFSafariViewController.

Comment: not possible to control cookie storage in SFSafari, that's part of security. SFSafari has same cookie storage as Safari and apple don't want devs to control it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to pass a cookie, but it is possible to do a seamless login if you control the backend side. You could implement an authorization scheme where you generate a short-lived token, and pass that token in the URL parameter that you load in the SFSafariViewController, such that the backend side uses it to start a session.

1. app issues a request to generate the token, backend generates it
2. app opens SFSafariViewController with the token
3. backend accepts the token, and returns a cookie
4. the web app can continue as if it was logged in

Comment: Can we do this the other way around? From SFSafariViewController to the main app?

Comment: Yes, this is possible too. You can register a custom URL scheme and handle the deep link in your app. If SFSafariViewController redirects the user to that link, you can handle it in the app (with any extra parameters you pass). See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app